# SQL server Rango de Fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, será que me podrían colaborar es q tengo el siguiente código que se ejecuta bien pero en el resultado de la consulta me esta ignorando el rango de fechas q le especifique, saben por q o como lo puedo arreglar.

```
    SELECT 
T3.DocDate,
T3.[DocNum],
T0.[ItemCode], 
T0.[ItemName], 
T1.[ItmsGrpNam], 
T0.[U_Subgrupo],
T2.[Quantity],
T2.[LineTotal], 
T4.[SlpName], 
T3.[CardName]
     FROM 
    [dbo].[OITM]  T0 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[OITB]  T1 ON T0.[ItmsGrpCod] = T1.[ItmsGrpCod] 
    INNER JOIN RDR1 T2 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode] 
    INNER JOIN ORDR T3 ON T2.[DocEntry] = T3.[DocEntry] 
    INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T2.[SlpCode] = T4.[SlpCode] 
    WHERE T3.[DocNum] LIKE '40%%' OR T3.DocNum LIKE '15%%' AND T3.DocDate BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20210401'
    ORDER BY T3.DocNum ASC
```

Nota: Aclaro que estoy estudiando el SQL, perdonen si hay llegue a ser un error muy bobo por decirlo de algún modo, Gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sin ver datos de entrada y salida, va a ser dificil ayyudarte...

Comment: DocDate es tipo datetime

Comment: ya veo, pero igual no podía cambiar a date ya que la hora se necesita, pero tendré en cuenta lo de poner datos para próximas ocasiones, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que el operador `AND` tiene mayor precedencia que el operador `OR`, la condición que estás escribiendo es equivalente a:

```sql
WHERE (T3.[DocNum] LIKE '40%%') OR (T3.DocNum LIKE '15%%' AND T3.DocDate BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20210401')
```

Esto quiere decir que a los registros que cumplen esta condición `T3.[DocNum] LIKE '40%%'` no se les evaluará la condición `T3.DocDate BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20210401'`.

Es por esto que te sugiero utilizar paréntesis para ser claro en cómo quieres que se evalúe una condición en SQL. De esta forma:

```sql
WHERE (T3.[DocNum] LIKE '40%%' OR T3.DocNum LIKE '15%%') AND (T3.DocDate BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20210401')
```

Y así se aplicaría la condición de las fechas para todos los registros que quieres consultar.

Comment: Eso era todo, gracias la verdad no pensé q los paréntesis afectaran a ese punto.